# Submit child's form via parent's button

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

#### (simplified) Architecture

- parent-component: has button and a mat-card as "content-view"
- child-component(s): contains form and will be displayed in the parent's content-view

I have multiple child components which can be displayed in the parent-component's content-view (only one at a time!). For the sake of reducing redundancy, I outsourced the save button to the parent's component.

My idea is to use the parent's button to save the child's form, by binding the child's save function to the button.
Like this:

```
class ChildComponent{

    form = new FormGroup {...}

    constructor() {
        parentComponent.setupButton(this.saveChildForm.bind(this));
    }

    saveChildForm(): void {
      if (this.form.valid) {
        // send to backend
      }

}
```

When clicking the button and having a valid (child-component) form, the data will be sent to the backend.

#### My question:

Is this approach breaking any "angular form best practices" or "- rules", 'cause I am using a form without a submit button?
Is there a better way to handle it?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You should save the state of your form in your parent component, for example on form `valueChanges` you can emit an event to the parent with all the form data. Then you can simply press the button and send the saved state of the form to your backend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The state should always be maintained in the top-most component.
All the other components should be *dumb*, it means that they should show some graphic, accept inputs and emit outputs.